# Visual Studio 2017 C++Debug/Release different output

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2017, stdvector

I've implemented a [Kolakoski's sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolakoski_sequence) with a low memory footprint, using the reference from Wikipedia

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

int IncrementPointer(std::vector<int>& vec, int k)
{
    if (vec.size() <= k)
    {
        vec.push_back(22);
    }

    if (vec[k] == 11)
    {
        vec[k] = 1;
        return 1;
    }
    else if (vec[k] == 22)
    {
        vec[k] = 2;
        return 2;
    }
    else if (vec[k] == 1)
    {
        vec[k] = IncrementPointer(vec, k + 1) == 1 ? 2 : 22;
        return 2;
    }
    else if (vec[k] == 2)
    {
        vec[k] = IncrementPointer(vec, k + 1) == 1 ? 1 : 11;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    long long iteration = 2;
    long long nextPowOf10 = 10;

    long long numOf1s = 1;

    std::vector<int> vec;

    std::cout << std::setw(15) << 'n' << std::setw(15) << "#1s" << std::setw(8) << "P(n)\n";
    std::cout << std::setw(15) << 1 << std::setw(15) << numOf1s << '\n';

    while (iteration++ <= 100'000'000'000'000)
    {
        int retvalue = IncrementPointer(vec, 0);
        if (retvalue == 1)
            ++numOf1s;
        if (iteration % nextPowOf10 == 0)
        {
            std::cout << std::setw(15) << nextPowOf10 << std::setw(15) << numOf1s << std::setw(8) << vec.size() << '\n';
            nextPowOf10 *= 10;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, the program internally calculates right elements of the sequence in Debug Mode and outputs expected results. So far, so good.

The problem starts in Release mode, vector gets optimized away (how could it be?), and the elements calculated are now wrong.

The expected sequence is [[1 2] 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 etc.], with first two are preset.
and in release mode the elements are [1 2] 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 ... Clearly, something wrong went on. And subsequently the output is unexpected, and the program crashes, with calling to malloc (so it does have somewhere vector reallocated).

What am I doing wrong? Is it simultaneous push_back to vector and update to the element of vector?

Answer (score 2):

I believe a construct like this exhibits undefined behavior:

```
vec[k] = IncrementPointer(vec, k + 1) == 1 ? 2 : 22;
```

It is unspecified whether `vec[k]` or `IncrementPointer(vec, ...)` gets evaluated first. `vec[k]` returns a reference to the corresponding element. If `IncrementPointer` is called later, it may push new elements into `vec` which in turn may cause it to reallocate, whereupon that reference becomes dangling.

Make it

```
int val = IncrementPointer(vec, k + 1);
vec[k] = val == 1 ? 2 : 22;
```

Comment: It indeed solved the problem. But why? should not it always evaluate rhs before it process assignment?

Comment: Both left-hand side and right-hand side are evaluated before the assignment is made, of course. But it is unspecified which side is evaluated first. You have a function call on both sides (`operator[]` on the left, `IncrementPointer` on the right) - these two calls are [intedeterminately sequenced](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).

Comment: Is not it a contradiction to rule 20) In every simple assignment expression E1=E2 and every compound assignment expression E1@=E2, every value computation and side-effect of E2 is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of E1?

Comment: @dEmigOd Hmm, indeed. This rule is new in C++17, so perhaps (some versions of) MSVC is simply non-conforming. Pre-C++17, E1 and E2 were unsequenced relative to each other.